# How to override Laravel model attribute?

Tags: php, laravel

As you can see bellow I cast the `external_urls`

```
class training extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'external_urls' => 'object'
    ];
```

This object looks like:

```
"external_urls": [
    {
       "url": "https://google.com/",
       "name": "test link"
    }
],
```

How to replace all `https://` in that object by `[[http:]]`

To have something like :

```
"external_urls": [
    {
        "url": "[[http:]]//google.com/",
        "name": "test link"
    }
],
```

Comment: Welcome, would [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking about [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

```
class training extends Model

{

    protected $casts = [
        'external_urls' => 'object'
    ];

    public function getExternalUrlsAttribute($value)
    {
        return str_replace("https:","[[http:]]",$value);
    }
```

should do the job.